# Mass Brick Settling Causing Excess Load On Center Beam

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, foundations

I live in a 115+ YO building and recently had my kitchen remodelled.  During this the subfloor was replaced (old 1x6s in bad shape).  I noticed a significant bow in the joists with the central steel beam being the high point.  East side of beam is 12' span and low point is 1/2" from joist height at beam.  West side span is 8' with a 1" low point.  My assumption is that the 3-4 layer brick wall is settling causing this.  My concern is that this action is transferring load from the brick to the central beam that could lead to failure.  I bought my unit 2 years ago and prior to this a different section of beam failed and was repaired (new concrete/columns etc..).  Should I be concerned that this may happen again?  Is there anything that can be done within reasonable cost?

Comment: you need a local structural engineer to look at your building.  It's possible it can be fixed reasonably, it's also possible it could cost $40,000